# Framing HTTP secure header filters for Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: apache, tomcat

I want to add security header for my Apache Tomcat 7 server. Checked out to see that **xssProtectionEnabled** filter would be required to add in the *web.xml* file of apache tomcat.

That is, I need to add these options in the config.

```
X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block"  
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff 
Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
```

Can someone help on how can the filter be framed to accompany these options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work via the tomcat filters [Container Provided Filters](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html) for your example there is an article [How to Enable Secure HTTP Header in Apache Tomcat 8?](https://geekflare.com/tomcat-http-security-header/)
The article will suggest to enable the follwing:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
  <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks PowerStat :)

Comment: will this enable Content-Security-Policy ?